# website head-menu with text and picture

Tags: css, html, html-lists

Please help me to solve my problem.
I need to make head menu with pictures.
Now i have:
[image]

What i need to do:
[image]

**My HTML code here:**

```
   <div id="head">
      <div class="site_info">
         <div id="tabs">
            <ul id="tabMenu">
               <li class="dropdown">
                  <div><a class="tab1">поиск по производителю</a></div>
               </li>
               <li class="dropdown">
                  <div><a class="tab2">поиск по назначению</a></div>
               </li>
               <li class="dropdown">
                  <div>
                     <span id="more_search"></span>
                     <a class="tab4" href="/emarket/cart/">покупки</a>
                  </div>
               </li>
               <li class="dropdown">
                  <div><a class="tab3">сравнение</a></div>
               </li>
               <li class="dropdown">
                  <div><a class="tab3">кабинет</a></div>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="work" umi:element-id="40">
         <div umi:field-name="order_info_top"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    #main #head div.site_info {
       padding-top: 45px;
    }

    #main #head div.site_info ul {
       width: 50%;
       margin: 0 auto;
       min-width: 1024px;
    }
    #main #head div.site_info ul li {
       display: inline;
       margin-right: 18px;
    }
    #main #head div.site_info ul li a.tab1 a.tab2 a.tab3 a.tab4 {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 89px;
    }
```

Comment: Add images to the list? Or as a background???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a height and width to the individual menu. Then add a style with your image as its background. Position the backgruond image top center.

### **HTML**

```
<div>
    <ul>
       <li class="dropdown"><div><a class="tab1">Menu 1</a></div></li>       
        <li class="dropdown"><div><a class="tab2">Menu 2</a></div></li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### **CSS**

```
li
{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width :100px;
}

.dropdown .tab1
{
    background : url('http://www.indievisionmusic.com/wp-content/themes/indievisionmusic/images/at_symbol_10x10.gif') no-repeat top center;
        padding-top: 10px;

}
.dropdown .tab2
{
    background : url('http://www.gigabyte.us/images/icon_blue.png') no-repeat top center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VjtNk/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just change your text for `<img src="images/image.jpg">`

And if you want it to be a link: `<a href="index.html"><img src="images/image.jpg" width="100" height="100"/></a>`

Answer (score 0):

you could just use images instead of text and add in the image using the CSS backgroundd feature

```
li a.tab1 { background: url(); width:XXpx; height: XXpx }
li a.tab2 { background: url(); width:XXpx; height: XXpx }
li a.tab3 { background: url(); width:XXpx; height: XXpx  }
```